# How can I estimate the amount of memory freed before a call to GC.Collect()?

Tags: c#, mpi

I am calling a native mpi-library from managed code and (occasionally) the system crashes showing nothing but the managed and the native stacktrace. This happens only during queued exchange of plenty large messages. (Queued means that no more than n large messages can be sent and/ or m large messages received concurrently by any process)

What I am suspecting is that messages created in C# remain in memory (waiting to be collected by the GC) and cannot be collected during the call to the native library. So the setup crashes when MPI_Alloc_mem requests memory.

Calling

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

before every message sent and/ or received is not an option by my program's design, so I am curious if there is a way to estimate how much memory would be freed if I would call the garbage collector now.

Thanks ahead,

Benj

```
Stacktrace:

at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MPI.Unsafe.MPI_Alloc_mem (intptr,intptr,intptr&) <0xffffffff>
at MPI.UnmanagedMemoryStream.AllocateMemory (long,bool&) <0x0004f>
at MPI.UnmanagedMemoryStream.Reserve (long) <0x0004f>
at MPI.UnmanagedMemoryStream.Write (byte[],int,int) <0x0007f>
at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write (int) <0x00094>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.WriteBinaryHeader (System.IO.BinaryWriter,bool) <0x00064>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream,object,System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]) <0x00079>
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream,object) <0x00018>
at MPI.Communicator.ImmediateSend<T> (T,int,int) <0x000fa>
at [somewhere in my program]

Native stacktrace:

    mono() [0x4a4305]
    mono() [0x4ff65f]
    mono() [0x416099]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x349de0f4a0]
    /gpfs/packages/gcc/openmpi/1.6/lib/libmpi.so(ompi_rb_tree_insert+0x1a) [0x2aaaacd71a5a]
    /gpfs/packages/gcc/openmpi/1.6/lib/libmpi.so(mca_mpool_base_alloc+0x402) [0x2aaaace2bc42]
    /gpfs/packages/gcc/openmpi/1.6/lib/libmpi.so(PMPI_Alloc_mem+0x9b) [0x2aaaacd914bb]
    [0x4132b6dc]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: That's not possible.  When you see a program failing to allocate unmanaged memory then suspecting a problem with the GC is not exactly the first thing to look for.

Comment: I think the debug info has the right direction: *Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a **fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application**.*

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for your response. I agree. However I am not suspecting a problem with the GC itself but in context of how my application is designed and interoperability with unmanaged code. Also it is not the first thing I am looking for.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Thank you for your response. I used mono-3.10, mono-3.9 and mono-git. I also used OpenMpi-1.6, OpenMpi-1.8 and OpenMpi-1.4 and they are all leading to the same error